# MVC5 MvcSiteMapProvider to display full sitemap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5, mvcsitemapprovider

I successfully installed MvcSiteMapProvider, and got the breadcrumbs working and customizing the templates to generate Twitter Bootstrap navbar menu. Everything is honky dory. Now I'd like to have a view which sole purpose would be to display the whole sitemap hierarchy (in a tree structure, nodes would be clickable).

I've found traces of old ASP.NET sitemap solution to XSLT transform the sitemap XML file. That's not only a dead-end because it's old and doesn't look like a good idea, but I also take advantage of the annotation feature of MvcSiteMapProvider.

I don't use external DI framework.

I turn to here because my search attempts came out empty. I guess I could do something like the bootstrap navbar customization, creating some templates. But I'm sure I'm not the first one and I'd be happy to see some working code if there any out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/HtmlHelper-extensions):

> **Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMap()** - Can be used to generate a list of all pages in your sitemap

If that doesn't meet your needs, you could always build your own custom HTML helper to display the SiteMap per your requirements. Have a look at [this answer](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/issues/363#issuecomment-58678912) for a demo showing how to create `Next` and `Back` links according to the document outline of the SiteMap.

Comment: I have to tell that `MvcSiteMapProvider` is great not only to display SiteMap, but it can generate breadcrumbs if needed, menu, and many more. Very flexible and configurable through annotation, visibility providers, ...